# url sharepoint list camlquery

Tags: wpf, list, sharepoint, url

I'm trying to collect my url and the description of the url stored in a column of a list from sharepoint and i don't know how to collect the URL value.

This is my code :

```
            var queryResultSaleListItems = clientContext.LoadQuery(listData);

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            //Read the Data into the Object
            var TipsList = from Tips in queryResultSaleListItems
                            select Tips;
            ObservableCollection<Tips> colTips = new ObservableCollection<Tips>();
            //Read Every List Item and Display Data into the DataGrid
            foreach (SPSClient.ListItem item in TipsList)
            {

                var tips = new Tips();
                tips.TitleTip = item.FieldValues.Values.ElementAt(1).ToString();
                tips.App = item.FieldValues.Values.ElementAt(4).ToString();
                //should collect the url 
                tips.URL = item.FieldValues.Values.ElementAt(5).ToString();
                //should collect the description of the url
                tips.URLdesc = item.FieldValues.Values.ElementAt(5).ToString();

                colTips.Add(tips);
            }
            ListboxTips.DataContext = colTips;
```

In my expression its >

((Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUrlValue)(item.FieldValues.Values.ElementAt(5))).Url

((Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUrlValue)(item.FieldValues.Values.ElementAt(5))).Description

Thanks for your help,

Comment: my url means which url of sharepoint ?

Comment: in a list of sharepoint you can create a type of column hyperlink .. so this is my url.

Answer (score 4):

Use `FieldUrlValue` for getting `hyperlink` field in `Client Object Model`.

Use Following Code:

```
        string server = "siteURL";
        var ctx = new ClientContext(server);
        var web = ctx.Web;
        var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("CustomList");
        var listItemCollection = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());  

        ctx.Load(listItemCollection);                      

        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem listItem in listItemCollection)
        {                
            string acturlURL =  ((FieldUrlValue)(listItem["URL"])).Url.ToString(); // get the Hyperlink field URL value
            string actdesc = ((FieldUrlValue)(listItem["URL"])).Description.ToString(); // get the Hyperlink field Description value
        }
```